# How to move this scrap of code from Oracle to Postgres

Tags: postgresql, migration

Can someone please let me know how to convert the below code from Oracle to Postgres database:

```
DECLARE
      TYPE parametro IS RECORD
      (
         b1  NUMBER,
         b2  NUMBER,
         b3  NUMBER,
         bf1  NUMBER,
         bf2  NUMBER,
         bf3  NUMBER
      );

     TYPE t_parametros IS TABLE OF parametro INDEX BY PLS_INTEGER;
     matriz t_parametros;
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you need to declare a [Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-createtype.html) and then declare an array of that type. However, the type declaration must be at the schema level, it cannot be within the `DO` block (Postgres equivalent of an Oracle anonymous block. So: (see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=b3aa0b72ea71c6667e305eef22d63976))

```
create type parametro as
       ( b1   numeric
       , b2   numeric
       , b3   numeric
       , bf1  numeric
       , bf2  numeric
       , bf3  numeric
       );

-- test 
do $$
declare 
    matriz parametro[];
begin
    matriz[1] = ( (1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6))::parametro ;
    matriz[2] = ( (10),(20),(30),(40),(50),(60))::parametro ;   
    raise notice 'Length of matriz[]: %', array_length(matriz,1); 
    raise notice 'matriz[1].b1,matriz[2].b1==>: %,%', matriz[1].b1, matriz[2].b1;     
end ; 
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin for your help. It was very useful to me.
now I leave another question on the same topic.